# React sending axios post request save data correctly., but not return response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, axios

I have an Axios post request in the react.js app.

**the data saved in the endpoint as expected**, but I'm not getting the response back. Instead, I'm getting caught "Network error."

Is there a problem with the way I'm sending the data?

Is it related to sending the request not from the server but directly from the front app?

Is it possible that the endpoint cannot send me a response because of a blocked port or something?

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData()
bodyFormData.append("supplier", "blabla")
bodyFormData.append("tranmode", "A")
bodyFormData.append("ccno", "blabla")
bodyFormData.append("expdate", "blabla")
bodyFormData.append("mycvv", "blabla")
bodyFormData.append("sum", "blabla")
bodyFormData.append("currency", "1")
bodyFormData.append("cred_type", "1")
bodyFormData.append("myid", "123456789")

  return axios
      .post(url, bodyFormData, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        //handle success
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

The error:

```
Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.y.onerror (xhr.js:117)
```

Comment: It is possible that the rest api is throwing error before sending response back to the request. Can you check on the backend if it is throwing any error?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297420/getting-network-error-when-calling-axios-get-request-in-react-js

Comment: please attach the network tab's image for more clarifications