# Getting axioserror network error at xmlhttprequest.handleerror when calling axios post request in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am new to this React.js axios concept and when I try to call axios.get, I get `AxiosError: Network Error` I'm not sure why this error is coming and I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297420/getting-network-error-when-calling-axios-get-request-in-react-js) and [this](https://www.brainstormcreative.co.uk/react-js/use-axios-in-react-to-post-api-data-example/) some other examples also but I didn't get the proper solution.

And I have install the below two commands

`npm install axios` and `npm install cors`

[image: package.json]

Below is my code :-

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";

function GetApiData() {

var data = {
    vendorname: "achintya",
      };
    
      const postData = () => {
        axios({
          method: "post",
          baseURL: "https://somesite.com",
          url: "/bkdb_getvendorcodes",
          payload: data,
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);//showing error here 
          });
      };
    
    return (
        <>
            <Button variant="outlined" onClick={postData}>POST data</Button>
        </>
    );
}

export default GetApiData;
```

When I run the above code I'm getting the below error

[image: network error]

But the service is working fine example img

[image: service is working]

I don't have much knowledge to fix this error please suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `allow cors origin in your backend server` or you can use an alternative approach for development you can use below extension.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf